# How to update the nested JSON file in DynamoDB

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

There is a map structure in DynamoDB and I wonder how we can update it. For example if the  map structure is like:
{A {B {C, D, E}}},
What code should I write if say I want to delete E or I want to delete B and all that are included in B (C,D,E)?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. Can you provide a more concrete example?

Answer (score 3):

For case:

1. Do an UpdateItem with `UpdateExpression="DELETE A.B.E"`
2. Do an UpdateItem with `UpdateExpression="DELETE A.B"`

Case 2 will delete the nested attribute E, as E is inside A.B, so case 2 is a superset of the change described by case 1.